# permissions for opening uri in android browser

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-internet

If an android app converts user input to a valid uri and the app launches a browser window with that uri, does the app need to declare `android.permission.INTERNET` or similar the manifest? On my own device it works fine without but I'm not sure if it's necessary in order for it to work on other devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean "starts an activity with an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` and that `Uri`", then  you do not need the `INTERNET` permission.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation the INTERNET permission is only required when your application creates network sockets, since in your case it is the browser that does the network operation and not your app then INTERNET permission is not necessary, this should be true for all phones.

Reference:
[INTERNET PERMISSION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET)